# How to create app icon for my flutter app without padding?

Tags: flutter

For my flutter app I have to set app icon without padding like Instagram, BookMyShow, etc,

I have used flutter_launcher_icons paackage to generate app icon, below is my pubspec.yaml configartion, but here when I generate the icon icons have padding, so I want to remove padding around my app icon for both Android and IOS so please help me.

Note - My icon have no any padding.

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icons/1024.png"
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  adaptive_icon_drawable: false
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

To remove padding around your app icon for both Android and iOS in your Flutter app, you can customize the image you provide to the flutter_launcher_icons package. The padding is typically controlled by the image itself. Ensure that your icon image is a square image with the icon centered within it, and it doesn't have any built-in padding.

Here are the steps to create an app icon without padding:

1:Ensure your app icon image is square and doesn't contain any padding. It should be properly centered within the square image.

2:Update your pubspec.yaml configuration as follows:

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
code:
flutter_icons:
android: true
ios: true
image_path: "assets/icons/1024.png"
adaptive_icon_background: null
icon background
adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icons/1024.png"

In this configuration, the adaptive_icon_background is set to null, which effectively removes the adaptive icon background. The adaptive_icon_foreground is set to the same image path as your app icon, ensuring it uses the same image for both the background and foreground. This will result in an icon without padding.
finally run the following command to generate the app icons:
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
After generating the icons, you should have an app icon without padding on both Android and iOS. Make sure your icon image is properly designed to be centered within the square canvas to achieve the desired appearance.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073